# Suricata does not detect "self" traffic

Tags: snort

I have built two simple rules

```
alert tcp any any -> any any (msg: "tcp detected"; sid: 2; rev: 1;)
alert udp any any -> any any (msg: "udp detected"; sid: 1; rev: 1;)
```

Then from the same machine I do an nmap

```
nmap -sU myipaddress
```

Issue is, I get alerts from all other traffic but for the nmap I do not get any alerts. Does suricata have a rule to ignore the kind of traffic that destination ip = origin ip?

Comment: That scan would be routed over the local loopback device. Is that device monitored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that you are sniffing the correct interface. nmap traffic may go on loopback one (using routing information) and you may sniffing the external iface.

If interface is correct and if you are using pcap capture you may want to add '-k none' option to avoid checksum offloading related problem.
Missing alerts often comes because suricata will ignore packets with invalid checksum. And checksum offloading on the card will cause that for locally emitted packets. So when you are using local traffic to test traffic you should take care of that. Solution is to used modern capture method like af_packet or pass '-k none' to stop validating checksum.

Comment: That seems to be exactly my comment as an answer, but it does not answer the question.

Comment: Indeed on first part of answer, sorry to have missed that.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second part as to how that is relevant to answering the question exactly?

Comment: Mising alerts often comes because suricata will ignore packets with invalid checksum. And checksum offloading on the card will cause that for locally emitted packets. So when you are using local traffic to test traffic you should take care of that. Solution is to used modern capture method like af_packet or pass '-k none' to stop vaiating checksum.

Comment: Could you edit that into the answer? https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/173358/edit

Comment: I just changed it to sudo suricata -c /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml -i lo --init-errors-fatal but now I am getting new errors:
13/11/2017 -- 10:56:37 - <Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_INVALID_VALUE(130)] - Frame size bigger than block size
13/11/2017 -- 10:56:37 - <Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_AFP_CREATE(190)] - Couldn't init AF_PACKET socket, fatal error
13/11/2017 -- 10:56:37 - <Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_FATAL(171)] - thread W#01-lo failed
Is there a particular config needed to capture traffic on loopback?

Comment: Solved it. I had to set the af-packet configuration in suricata as:
`af-packet:
  - interface: lo
    cluster-id: 99
    cluster-type: cluster_flow
    defrag: yes
    use-mmap: yes
    tpacket-v3: yes
    block-size: 73728
`
the run suricata using
 `sudo suricata -c /etc/suricata/suricata.yaml --af-packet --init-errors-fatal -k none`